# A Symbol Name was Expect by 'id"

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to make a table for a login system for a simple website project but I'm having this error that I wasn't having the other day. I'm getting the errors at 'id' and unsigned on the 2nd line. The error is "A Symbol Name is Expected Near 'id'. I also get an error by unsigned on the same line that says "unrecognizable statement type". I am using XAMPP.

```
CREATE TABLE 'users' (
    'id' int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'username' varchar(75) NOT NULL,
    'password' varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    'email' varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    'phone' varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    'address' varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
    UNIQUE KEY 'email' ('email')
    ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: What database and version are you using? And what is the error message?

Comment: I added the errors I was getting to my post but I don't know how to check what version I'm using. I'm using xampp.

Comment: If it's MySQL, or MariaDB, `select version()`

Answer (score 2):

You're using single quotes for identifiers (column and table names). Single quotes are for strings.

Identifiers are either unquoted, or use the MySQL/MariaDB specific `` ` ``. The SQL standard uses `"`. Consider turning on [ANSI mode](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/#ansi) for compatibility.

Also consider using the [`serial` shorthand](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/auto_increment/) for `bigint unsigned not null auto_increment unique`.

```
create table users (
  id serial primary key,
  ...
)
```